# Error 1064 while creating procedure in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure in MySQL but I am getting an error 1064:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ZID_TRANSAKSI VARCHAR(64),
   ZTGL1 DATE,
   ZTGL2 DATE 
) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE ...' at line 2

--------------------------------------------------

Query: DELIMITER;

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

This is the query of the procedure that I want to create:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE HITUNGMASUK 
(
   ZID_TRANSAKSI VARCHAR(64),
   ZTGL1 DATE,
   ZTGL2 DATE 
) 

BEGIN 
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE PTAHUN VARCHAR(4);
   DECLARE PBULAN VARCHAR(2);
   DECLARE PHITUNG INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
   DECLARE CEKKARTUSTOK INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE PID_BARANG VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'X';
   DECLARE PPANJANG INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE CEKKARTUSTOK CURSOR FOR
   SELECT B.id_barang, SUM(B.total_Panjang) AS PANJANG
      FROM transaksi_gudang A,
           line_item_barang B
      WHERE A.ID_Transaksi LIKE ZID_TRANSAKSI 
      AND   A.Tanggal BETWEEN ZTGL1 AND ZTGL2
      AND   B.ID_GR = A.ID_Transaksi
      GROUP BY B.id_barang;
    
   DECLARE
     CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
   SET
    done = TRUE;


   PTAHUN = YEAR(ZTGL1);
   PBULAN = MONTH(ZTGL1);
  
   OPEN CEKKARTUSTOK;
   teams_loop:
   LOOP
      FETCH CEKKARTUSTOK INTO PID_BARANG,PPANJANG;
   
       IF PID_BARANG = 'X' THEN
          INSERT INTO kartustok(TAHUN,BULAN,ID_BARANG,KODE_GUDANG,MASUK) VALUES ();
       END IF;    
   
      IF done THEN LEAVE teams_loop;
      END IF;

   END LOOP;
  CLOSE CEKKARTUSTOK;


   
   SELECT 
   FROM kartustok C 
   WHERE C.TAHUN = PTAHUN
   AND   C.BULAN = PBULAN
   AND   C.ID_BARANG = P
   
   
END $$ DELIMITER;
```

Why is my query giving an `Error Code: 1064`? How can I fix it?

I used to work with ORACLE databases and I have just started working with MySQL. Let me know if there are any differences that I am not aware of.

Comment: The last `SELECT` that ends with `C.ID_BARANG = P` is missing a terminating `;`.

Answer (score 0):

`DELIMITER` is only required if you create the procedure within your command line client to differentiate between the regular delimiter and a delimiter inside a BEGIN END block.

In your example you define a delimiter `$$ CREATE PROCEDURE HITUNGMASUK` which is probably not what you really want.

`DELIMITER $$` needs to be executed as a single command, not concatenated with the definition of a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE()
BEGIN
...
END
$$
```